# Create a tkinter button in separate class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making my first real Tkinter application in Python 3.4. I have made a few simpler things with Tkinter, but nothing as advanced as this one.

Part of my program is to have a window that has two buttons, one on each side, and a picture in the middle. The buttons will navigate through pictures to the left and right.

I want my buttons to be able to be created through a separate class NavButton so my code is more organized and easier to read like in this picture from the question [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application).

[image]

Essentially I want to say:

```
self.left_button = NavButton(self, ">")
```

or something similar to create a

```
class NavButton():
```

object.

Then pack it with

```
self.left_button.pack()
```

I am struggling with how to actually make a button be set up in a different class. It keeps saying 'AttributeError: 'NavButton' object has no attribute 'tk'
'

Here is my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand = True)

        self.left_button = NavButton(frame, ">")
        self.left_button.pack(side='left', fill='y')

class NavButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, icon):
        self.nav_button = tk.Button(master, text=icon, width=25)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Viewer")
root.geometry('1000x600')
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Could my problem come from the way I create the buttons?

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ...)
```

VS

```
self.frame = tk.Frame(parent)
```

So in a nutshell, how do I use a separate class for my button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NavButton` is a frame. I would make it a button, that's what you want, isn't it? Change this:

```
class NavButton(Tk.Frame):
```

to

```
class NavButton(Tk.Button):
```

Also, you should call the parent initializer:

```
super().__init__(self, **options)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I had tried making it a Button but that hadn't helped.. So because it is a child of the tk.Button class I just call the constructor of the parent?